# Interpolating along the 2-D image slices

Tags: matlab, 2d, volume, interpolation, visualize

I have a set of **100** 2-D image slices of the same size. I have used MATLAB to stack them to create a volumetric data. While the size of the 2-D slices is 480x488 pixels, the direction in which the images are stacked is not wide enough to visualize the volume in different orientation when projected. I need to interpolate along the slices to increase the size for visualization.

Can somebody please give me an idea or tip about how to do it?

Edit: Anotated projected microscopy-images

[image: Looking at a face]

[image: General view]

The figure 1 is the top-view of the projected volume.

The figure 2 is the side-view of the projected volume.

When I change the rotation-angle, and try to visualize the volume in different orientation, e.g. side-view (figure 2), is what I see as in figure 2.

I want to expand the side view by interpolating along the image slices.

Comment: In what kind of application are you working on? Is it related to medical imaging (e.g. CT)?

Comment: Alceu, I am working on microscopy images.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an adapted example from the [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/visualize/f5-3291.html) on how to visualize volumetric data (similar to yours) using [isosurfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosurface):

```
%# load MRI dataset: 27 slices of 128x128 images
load mri
D = squeeze(D);       %# 27 2D-images

%# view slices as countours
contourslice(D,[],[],1:size(D,3))
colormap(map), view(3), axis tight

%# apply isosurface
figure
%#D = smooth3(D);
p = patch( isosurface(D,5) );
isonormals(D, p);
set(p, 'FaceColor',[1,.75,.65], 'EdgeColor','none')
daspect([1 1 .5]), view(3), axis tight, axis vis3d
camlight, lighting gouraud

%# add isocaps
patch(isocaps(D,5), 'FaceColor','interp', 'EdgeColor','none');
colormap(map)
```

[image: contourslice]
[image: isosurface_isocaps]

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB has a function `interp3` that can be used for interpolation, assuming that the data is uniformly discretised.

Check out the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp3.html).

Hope this helps.

EDIT: The MATLAB function `interp3` works as follows:

```
vi = interp3(x, y, z, v, xi, yi, zi);
```

I assume that your "stack" of slices defines the arrays `x, y, z, v` as `3D` arrays, where `x, y` are the coordinates of the pixels in the plane, `z` is the "height" of each slice and `v` is the actual image slices, maybe as "intensity" values for the pixels.

If you want to interpolate new image slices at intermediate `z` values you could specify these levels in the `zi` array. The arrays `xi, yi` would again represent the coordinates of the pixels in the plane.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Darren. I am basically trying to add slices between slices. I could not understand what you mean by "uniformly discretized" data. I am fairly new to this. Can you please help me understand by elaborating it.

Comment: See my edit for a bit more info. If this doesn't help, maybe post a few more details about your problem. A "uniform discretisation" in this case means that the data is structured according to a Cartesian grid (as opposed to a scattered triangulation for example) - I'm fairly confident that your problem is uniform.

Comment: +1 as @DarrenEngwirda explained, 2D image slices have uniform grid locations (pixel locations and slice height). If for some reason that's not the case, you can use `griddata3`/`TriScatteredInterp` to interpolate scattered data...

Comment: Darren, and Amro, thanks for explaining about "uniform discretization". Regarding interpolation, I am at sixes and sevens. I am working on visualization of microscopy-images. I have edited my post by annotationg some projected images. Hoping to get some suggestions and help.

Comment: Hello Darren. I am still not able to figure it out. Can you help me understand a bit more about using interp3 for this particular application?

Answer (score 0):

I created a function to interpolate along image slices. Below is the code:

```
    function res = interp_along_slices( vol, scale )
    % Interpolation along the image slices

    % Get the size of the volume
      [r c p] = size(vol);

    % Pre-allocate the array:
    % the third dimension is scale times the p
      vol_interp = zeros(r,c,scale*p);

    % interpolate along the image slices 
      for inr = 1:r;
          for jnr = 1:c;
              xi = vol(inr,jnr,:);
              vol_interp(inr,jnr,:) = interp(xi, scale); 
          end;
      end;

      res = vol_interp;

    end
```