# Render 3D Volume from 2D Image Stack

Tags: c++, opengl, volumes

I have been brought in on a project where I need to render a 3D volume from a series of images of the volume. The images have been created by a couple of techniques such that they are vertical slices of the object in question.

The data set is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891154/creating-3d-volume-from-2d-slice-set-of-grayscale-images), but the asker is looking for a Matlab solution.

The goal is to have this drawing be in something near real time (>1Hz update rate), and from my research openGL seems to be the fastest option for drawing. Is there a built in function in openGL render the volume in openGL other than the following psuedocode algorithm.

```
foreach(Image in Folder)
     foreach(Pixel in Image)
        pointColour(pixelColour)
        pointLocation(Pixel.X,Pixel.Y,Image.Z)
        drawPoint
```

I am not concerned about interpolating between images, the current spacing is small enough that there no need for it.

Comment: Please rephrase your question if you intent was to RENDER the 3D volume, not just create the 3D texture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid if you're thinking about volume rendering, you will need to first understand the [volume rendering integral](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~kmorel/documents/dissertation/thesis_full/node9.html) because the resultant color of a pixel on the screen is a function of all the voxels that line up with it for the current viewing angle.

There are two methods to render a volume in real-time using conventional graphics hardware.

1. Render the volume as a set of 2D view-aligned slices that intersect the 3D texture (proxy geometry). Explanation [here](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch39.html).
2. Use a raycaster that uses programmable graphics hardware, tutorial [here](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~trier/?page_id=98).

This is not an easy problem to solve - but depending on what you need to do things might be a little simpler. For example: Do you care about having an interactive transfer function? Do you want perspective views, or will orthographic projection suffice? Are you rendering iso-surfaces? Are you using this only for [MPR-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_computed_tomography#Multiplanar_reconstruction) views?

Comment: Thanks for the help and links. It will not need MPR type view, although they seem to be starting with similar data to what I have, so I am going to look further into what is being done there. 

An orthographic view is all that is needed. Iso-surfaces are not going to be needed either, nor am I concerned with an interactive transfer function.