# 3D image in MATLAB using different images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, matlab, matlab-cvst

I have a set of images of a scene at different angles and the camera intrinsic parameters. I was able to generate the 3D points using point correspondences and triangulation. Is there a built-in method or a way to produce 3D images in MATLAB? From the given set of images, a 3D image as such? By 3D image, I mean a 3D view of the scene based on the colors, depth, etc.?

Comment: So you already have a depth map, you just need to display the image + depth?

Comment: @Lakshmi Narayanan   Have you checked this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891154/creating-3d-volume-from-2d-slice-set-of-grayscale-images/6894938#6894938

Comment: @portforwardpodcast I obtained the 3d points and displayed them, but they weren't anywhere close, due to no.of inliers and outliers from matching. If you mean the 3d points as depth, yes I have. But i wanted a 3D sort of effect, which I think are explained in the answers below

Answer (score 3):

There was a recent [MathWorks blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2013/10/04/easy-visualization-of-volumetric-data/) on 3D surface rendering, which showed methods using built-in functions and using contributed code.

The built-in method uses [`isosurface`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html) and [`patch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html). To display multiple surfaces, the trick is to set the `'FaceAlpha'` [`patch` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch_props.html) to get transparency.

The post also highlighted the ["vol_3d v2" File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22940-vol3d-v2), which provides the `vol3d` function to render the surface. It allows explicit definition of voxel colors and alpha values.

Answer (score 1):

Some file exchange from mathworks:
[3D CT/MRI images interactive sliding viewer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29134-3d-ctmri-images-interactive-sliding-viewer), [3D imshow](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41334-imshow3d-3d-imshow), [image3](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21881-image3), and [viewer3D](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21993-viewer3d).

If your images matrix `I` has the dimension of `x*y*z`, you can try `surface` as well:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(I,2), 1:size(I,1));
Z = ones(size(I,1),size(I,2));
for z=1:size(I,3)
   k=z*sliceInterval;
   surface('XData',X, 'YData',Y, 'ZData',Z*k,'CData',I(:,:,z), 'CDataMapping','direct', 'EdgeColor','none', 'FaceColor','texturemap')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB includes a function called `estimateUncalibratedRectification`, which you can use to rectify a pair of stereo images. Check out this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/stereo-image-rectification.html) of how to create a 3-D image, which can be viewed with a pair of red-cyan stereo glasses.