# Stacking of 2D files into 3D volume

Tags: matlab

I have a couple of 2D grayscale images i will like to stack up to create a 3D volume rendering in MATLAB. My problem im new to matlab but a i know a few basics to image processing. Some step wise approach in stacking up 2D images to form a 3D volume will be very appreciated.

Thanks all.

Comment: you can choose the dimensions of the 2D image pixels freely: will they be along (width, height), along (width, depth) or (height, depth)? similarly you can interpret 3D matrices any way you like. just one example: `mat(:, :, i) = img` for the i-th image `img`, here height and width will be in the first and second dimension of `mat` respectively.

Comment: I need a methodical approach of stacking the files. Is there any source code for that?

Comment: did you find this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6894938/3426025

Comment: BeyelerStudios i looked through the links but it was not of much help. Probably because im not that much good in coding. i was wondering if there were any other links with much simpler scripting.